# What is the difference between specifying the types explicitly vs. not specifying explicitly in Kotlin?

Tags: variables, kotlin

For example, what is the difference between this:

```
var serviceItem: String = "Haircut"
```

And

```
var serviceItem = "Haircut"
```

Comment: There is no difference. You put type annotations when the compiler can't infer the type; or the code is complex, and hence you want to annotate the type for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples you gave are equivalent.

However, there are a number of cases where you might want to specify it explicitly.

The most straightforward is if you want the member type to be of a superclass:

```kotlin
val list: List<Foo> = ArrayList<Foo>()
```

Another would be if you have some complex expression where the type is not obvious and you want it to be obvious to people who aren't looking at it in an IDE with type hinting turned on (such as a code review). It can also be error-proofing in that scenario: you may want to make sure you don't accidentally refactor it to something that's *not* `List<Foo>`:

```kotlin
val list: List<Foo> = foo.bar.getBaz().frobnicateWith(bar.foo)
```

Sometimes you're trying to provide a hint to the type inference for the expression initializing it (in this case, you'd otherwise have to use `mutableListOf<Foo>()`:

```kotlin
val list: MutableList<Foo> = mutableListOf()
```

As [gidds pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62549363/what-is-the-difference-between-specifying-the-types-explicitly-vs-not-specifyin/62549686#comment110616866_62549686), you might also do this if the initializing expression is of a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types):

```kotlin
val foo = LinkedList<Int>().apply { add(1) }
val bar: Int = foo.first // bar would otherwise be of type Int!
```

Comment: A further reason is if the initialiser returns a platform type, and you want to tell the compiler whether to treat it as nullable or not.

Comment: @gidds Great point, thanks!  I added that to my answer with an example (and a link to your comment for credit, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. Kotlin manages type declaration for you so you do not need to specify the type. It's useful in class hierarchy as mentioned in the docs:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/declaring-variables.html

> ### Specifying the type explicitly
>
> If you really want to, you can both initialize and specify the type on the same
> line. This is mostly useful if you're dealing with a class hierarchy (more on
> that later) and you want the variable type to be a base type of the value's
> class:
>
> ```
> val characters: CharSequence = "abc"
> ```